# PHP, Регулярные выражения: достать все попадающие под условия подстроки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, которая содержит группу номеров. Количество групп заранее неизвестно, но не менее одной. Известно, что номера вводятся строго через пробел и каждый номер состоит строго из 4 цифр. Необходимо составить такое регулярное выражение, которое бы доставало все номера из строки. При этом в случае когда один из номеров не соответствует формату, регулярка отрабатывать не должна.

Пример 1:

строка:
`1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666`

ожидаемый результат:
`["1111", "2222", "3333", "4444", "5555", "6666"]`

Пример 2:

строка:
`1111 222 3333`

ожидаемый результат:
`[]`

Я пытался делать через `preg_match_all()` с таким выражением: `/\A(\d\d\d\d\s?)+\z/`. Оно отрабатывает на всю строку, но достает только последний номер. То есть из первого примера я получаю только `4444`. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Вы хотите от регулярных выражений в PHP большего, что они могут дать.

Answer (score 1):

А так:

```
^(\d{4} )*?\d{4}$
```

^ - начало строки

(\d{4} )*? - начинается с произвольного количества групп "1234_"

$ - конец строки

\d{4}$ - заканчивается на одну группу из 4-х цифр

```js
preg_match_all('/^(\d{4} )*?\d{4}$/', '1234 5678 5668', $matches);
print_r(json_encode(explode(' ', $matches[0][0])));
```

https://onlinegdb.com/n077qhBgi

Answer (score 1):

Используйте двухэтапный подход: валидируйте строку с помощью вашего регулярного выражения и `preg_match`, а потом разбейте строку (если валидна) по пробелам:

```php
$str = "1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666";
if (preg_match('~\A(?:\d{4}\s?)+\z~', $str)) {
// if (preg_match('~\A\d{4}(?:\s\d{4})*\z~', $str)) { // или так, если в конце не должно быть пробельных символов
    print_r(preg_split('~\s~', $str));
//    print_r(explode(' ', $str)); // если пробелы обычные
}
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://3v4l.org/7HhgU).

Можно, конечно, придумать нечто экзотическое и объединить валидацию и извлечение в один `preg_match_all`:

```php
$str = "1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666";
if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)\s?|\A(?=(?:\d{4}\s?)+\z))(\d{4})~', $str, $m)) {
    print_r($m[1]);
}
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://3v4l.org/cGs6n). Однако очень мало кто разберёт, что здесь к чему.

- `(?:\G(?!\A)\s?|\A(?=(?:\d{4}\s?)+\z))` - одно из двух:

  - `\G(?!\A)\s?` - конец предыдущего совпадения и опциональный пробельный символ
  - `|` - или
  - `\A(?=(?:\d{4}\s?)+\z)` - начало строки, сразу после которого должны следовать 1 и более последовательностей из четырёх цифр и одного необязательного пробельного символа до конца строки
- `(\d{4})` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: четыре цифры.